# Mouseover Line on multiple charts when hover on single chart using D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

Please advice If there is any difficulty in understanding the question. so that, I can edit the question and provide the required information.

I want to show the Line and tooltip on multiple charts when I hover on single chart.

In the following chart, I am able to get the line on single chart, I want that the line should continue till the X-axis and also tooltip for highlighted value on multiple charts.

Following is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harsha547/h8bk5Lbm/7/) which I have worked till now.

```js
                            $(window).load(function () {
                                                   var textareas$ = $('#chartarea g');
                                                        textareas$.hide();
                        
                        $('input[name="Air"]').change(function () {
                                                    var elem$ = $(this);
                                                    var correspelem$ = textareas$.eq(elem$.val() - 1);
                                                        
                                                        if (elem$.val() == 1) {
                                                                                select('Retail', "#Retail");
                                                                } else if (elem$.val() == 2) {
                                                                                select("Gas", "#Gas");
                                                                } else if (elem$.val() == 3) {
                                                                                select("Dining", "#Dining");
                                                                } else {};
                                                                if (elem$.is(':checked')) correspelem$.show();
                                                                else correspelem$.hide();

                                                               var lastSelectedChartIndex;
                var chartAxis = document.querySelectorAll('#chartarea  .axis.x');
                
                var selectedCharts = document.querySelectorAll('#options input').forEach((elem, index) => {
                if (elem.checked) {
                 lastSelectedChartIndex = index;
                }
                });
                
                //console.log(lastSelectedChartIndex)
                
                chartAxis
                 .forEach((elem, index) => (index !== chartAxis.length - 1) && !(index == lastSelectedChartIndex) ? elem.style.display = 'none' : elem.style.display = 'block')

                                                        });
                                                });
```

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: Please provide the hint on how to approach the problem. so that I can figure out..

Comment: Please use the checkboxes to display the graph

Comment: You need to propagate your event on all svg to accomplish this. You could create a `setLinePosition` method on you chart, that would provide the value to your other charts in the callback, then for each chart set the line position according to the value received

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please provide the code skeleton for setLinePosition,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated you [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evu06039/2/) to have something working. I used VSCode and reindented the code, I hope it is ok for you. What I did is:

- Create an event dispatcher in the chart
- Creating a callback on the dispatcher event
- Select all lines
- Set their position

The callback looks like this:

```
chart.onHover(function (x) {
    console.log(x);
    d3.selectAll('.hover-line')
        .select('line')
        .attr('x1', x)
        .attr('x2', x)
        .style('opacity', 1)
})
```

This works, but I don't like the fact that everything gets reselected every time. It should be possible to subscribe to the event directly when calling `chart`, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Thank You !! Is there any way that I could join both the lines when I mouseover, and also I want to show the y-value as tooltip or label when hover.